# Fontconfig-like searching system font files on Android(native)

Tags: android, fonts, android-ndk, truetype

Is there any fontconfig-like way to search system font files on Android?

My game UI library provides a ttf font rendering. Someone just specify at least "human-readable" name, italic flag and font weight. The only way I found is just hardcode paths to system fonts in code, but it does not reliable and can't consider weight and italic parameters.

Maybe there is a file, which I can parse and get system font names from it?

On Linux I use fontconfig, I can use it on Android too, but I don't want to have completely useless megabytes in APK.

Answer (score 0):

You can now [query Google Fonts API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html), with the latest Support Library. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but maybe you'd like to consider this approach.

Comment: It seems available only since Oreo. Maybe I should look into support library source code and find reliable font config files.

Comment: I don't think you need to necessarily target Oreo to use Support Library 26. I mean, it's supposed to be retro-compatible...